# XAMPP instance already exists

Tags: php, sql, xampp

I don't have any windows of XAMPP open but for some reason I still have a localhost at port 8080 running. But when I try to reopen XAMPP it says that port 8080 is already in use but I don't have any windows of XAMPP running. I tried looking in my activity monitor but I can't find anything. Please help. I'll answer any questions.

Comment: Basically I cannot access the files that are in the localhost:8080 because i can't find the window.

Answer (score 0):

run `netstat -noa` and findout whether XAMPP is running in port 8080 by comparing the process identifier. It might be some other application running in port 8080.

Comment: Thanks yeah, I found out that it was XAMPP on the port, but in the activity monitor I found the XAMPP program running so I quit out of it. But sadly now I can't access the htdocs folder for the XAMPP. I only have access to a blank htdocs folder.